# getting timestamp in php

Tags: php, timespan

How can I get the timestamp of a desired hour?  The hour is in a variable that the user set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$hr = 10;
echo strtotime("today +$hr hours");
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [mktime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) function to build timestamp of any datetime.