# Get timestamp of today and yesterday in php

Tags: php, timestamp

How can I get the timestamp of 12 o'clock of today, yesterday and the day before yesterday by using strtotime() function in php?

12 o'clock is a variable and would be changed by user.

Comment: Depends on how you store the 12 o'clock (hours, minutes, seconds?). In general, did you have a look at the functions listed in (http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php)? What did you try so far?

Comment: definite duplicate of [getting timestamp in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772953/getting-timestamp-in-php) - You already asked that yesterday. The only difference is the arguments you pass to these functions. You can find the possible relative formats in the [PHP Manual](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php)

Comment: @Gordon: i am sorry.i am really stupid today.i wanted to delete it but it has some answer now and i can't delete it.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

```
$hour = 12;

$today              = strtotime($hour . ':00:00');
$yesterday          = strtotime('-1 day', $today);
$dayBeforeYesterday = strtotime('-1 day', $yesterday);
```

Comment: +1 and i know its nitpicking but I would prefer `$today = strtotime($hour . ":00:00");`

Comment: @Hannes Then I'd prefer `$hour . ':00:00'`. If you don't need variable interpolation, use single quotes. :o)

Comment: strtotime(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function

Comment: `strtotime('yesterday')` seems to work on my system.

Answer (score 17):

strtotime supports a number of [interesting modifiers](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php) that can be used:

```
$hour = 12;

$today              = strtotime("today $hour:00");
$yesterday          = strtotime("yesterday $hour:00");
$dayBeforeYesterday = strtotime("yesterday -1 day $hour:00");

echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s\n", $today);
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s\n", $yesterday);
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s\n", $dayBeforeYesterday);
```

It works as predicted:

```
2011-01-24 12:00:00
2011-01-23 12:00:00
2011-01-22 12:00:00
```

Answer (score 14):

OO Equivalent

```
$iHour = 12;

$oToday = new DateTime();
$oToday->setTime($iHour, 0);

$oYesterday = clone $oToday;
$oYesterday->modify('-1 day');

$oDayBefore = clone $oYesterday;
$oDayBefore->modify('-1 day');

$iToday     = $oToday->getTimestamp();
$iYesterday = $oYesterday->getTimestamp();
$iDayBefore = $oDayBefore->getTimestamp();

echo "Today: $iToday\n";
echo "Yesterday: $iYesterday\n";
echo "Day Before: $iDayBefore\n";
```

Answer (score 4):

to get start of day yesterday

```
$oDate = new DateTime(); 
$oDate->modify('-1 day'); 
echo $oDate->format('Y-m-d 00:00:00');
```

result

```
2014-11-05 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 4):

You can easily find out any date using `DateTime` object, It is so flexible

```
$yesterday = new DateTime('yesterday');
echo $yesterday->format('Y-m-d');

$firstModayOfApril = new DateTime('first monday of april');
echo $firstModayOfApril->format('Y-m-d');

$nextMonday = new DateTime('next monday');
echo $nextMonday->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: `$days = 7;
(new DateTime("now -{$days} days"))->format('c');`

Answer (score 1):

All the answers here are too long and bloated, everyone loves one-lines ;)

```
$yesterday = Date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 day'));
```

(Or if you are American you can randomize the date unit order to m/d/y (or whatever you use) and use Cups, galloons, feet and horses as units...)

Answer (score 0):

As of PHP 7 you can write something like [this](https://3v4l.org/WRX1P):

```
$today = new \DateTime();
$yesterday = (clone $today)->modify('-1 day');
$dayBefore = (clone $yesterday)->modify('-1 day');
// Then call ->format('Y-m-d 00:00:00'); on each objects
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use `new DateTime("now")` for today `new DateTime("1 day ago")` for yesterday or all can be parse by [strtotime](http://www.php.net/strtotime) php function.

Then format as you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
$timeStamp = time();
// $timeStamp = time() - 86400;

if (date('d.m.Y', $timeStamp) == date('d.m.Y')) {    
  echo 'Today'; 
} elseif (date('d.m.Y', $time) == date('d.m.Y', strtotime('-1 day'))) {     
  echo 'Yesterday';
}
```