# PHP date yesterday

Tags: php, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get timestamp of today and yesterday in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780333/get-timestamp-of-today-and-yesterday-in-php)

I was wondering if there was a simple way of getting yesterday's date through this format:

```
date("F j, Y");
```

Answer (score 233, accepted):

[`date()`](http://php.net/date) itself is only for formatting, but it accepts a second parameter.

```
date("F j, Y", time() - 60 * 60 * 24);
```

To keep it simple I just subtract 24 hours from the unix timestamp.

A modern oop-approach is using [`DateTime`](http://php.net/book.datetime)

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->sub(new DateInterval('P1D'));
echo $date->format('F j, Y') . "\n";
```

Or in your case (more readable/obvious)

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->add(DateInterval::createFromDateString('yesterday'));
echo $date->format('F j, Y') . "\n";
```

(Because `DateInterval` is negative here, we must [`add()`](http://php.net/datetime.add) it here)

See also: [`DateTime::sub()`](http://php.net/datetime.sub) and [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/class.dateinterval)

Comment: very good answer, there are many ways to do it but you have the simple one, short and easy to understand ( + the OOP one for those interested in using more RAM ;)

Comment: @neofutur Beside "we want to waste our RAM" the OOP-approach is useful, when you already have either a `DateTime`-, or a `DateInterval`-object (or both), which may be the case in an OOP-based application (e.g. `$customer->expire->add(DateInterval::createFromDateString('+1 year')) // customer paid for one additional year`) Also note, that `DateInterval` understands ISO8601 for time intervals, but `date()` doesn't. At the end of course: Select the one you better fit your needs :)

Comment: This is NOT a correct answer!! Daylight savings makes 23 and 25 hour days. So this is NOT giving you a good answer 2 hours of the year!!!

Comment: @patrick Interesting point :) Yes, you are right, but this is only true for the first solution, not the following utilizing `DateInterval`.

Comment: $yesterday          = strtotime("-1 day", $today);

Comment: Don't forget to use it as `\DateTime` and `\DateInterval` in the context of a namespace.

Answer (score 145):

[`strtotime()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php), as in `date("F j, Y", strtotime("yesterday"));`

Comment: +1 because this makes the intent a bit more obvious when scanning through the code. Self-documenting code and all that.

Answer (score 111):

How easy :)

```
date("F j, Y", strtotime( '-1 days' ) );
```

**Example:**

```
echo date("Y-m-j H:i:s", strtotime( '-1 days' ) ); // 2018-07-18 07:02:43
```

**Output:**

```
2018-07-17 07:02:43
```

Comment: I prefer this answer. The offset ('-1') doesn't have to be a constant: it can be built with a variable,even with a loop: `strtotime( '-'.$s.' days' )` where `$s` is how many days back (or forward if playing with signs) you want to go.

Comment: i needed five days ago so this one is easiest to modify.

Comment: Use `Y-m-d` instead of `Y-m-j` for the ISO standard date, `j` doesn't have a leading zero.