# Set date to yesterdays date

Tags: php, codeigniter, date

I have this piece of code which sets the date to 360 days later, 
I would like to know how to change this piece of code to make the date yesterdays date, 28/3/2016

```
$tmpdate = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d"));
            $tmpdate->add(new DateInterval('P360D'));
            $Available = $tmpdate->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: The future date is impossible if integer size is 32bit. Pass the date directly as string to the constructor.

Comment: what about yesterdays ?

Comment: `$tmpdate->sub(new DateInterval('P1D'));`

Comment: if you use the datepicker then you can use like. $('#date').datepicker('setDate', '28/3/2016');

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP date yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796866/php-date-yesterday)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that:

```
date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-1 day")); // yesterday (based on server date)
```

For any other date you can use strtotime:

```
strtotime("30-12-9999");
```

I hope it helps you!

Regards.

Comment: Thank you! I wanted this basically.

Answer (score 1):

Yesterday:

```
echo date("Y m d h:i",time() -60*60*24); // 24 hours ago.
echo date("Y m d",time() -60*60*24); // yesterday as in date.
```

As mark pointed out below I did not think of daylight savings. So...

```
$date = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('Europe/Stockholm')); // Change to suit
$Heretime = $date->format('H');
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$Difftime = $date->format('H') - $Heretime;

echo date("Y m d h:i",time() -60*60*(24-$Difftime)); // 24 hours ago in UTC.
echo date("Y m d",time() -60*60*(24-$Difftime)); // yesterday as in date in UTC.
```

And from there you can convert it back I guess... Or maybe I'm completely lost?

Comment: Not if you'e on the cusp of daylight savings.... you're assuming that every day is identical in length

Comment: True... In that case I guess you need to match the time with UTC time to see if it's daylight savings?