# Default date formatting with date_popup

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I'm using the Drupal 6 $form hook to create a date field and pop up.

My default is today's date and time 00:00:00.

I would like the default date to be yesterday and at a time of my choice, which could then be overwritten by the user in the client. I've been looking through the documentation but can't find anything that fits the bill.

As always, any help would be appreciated.

Many thanks.

```
$form['create_from'] = array(
  '#type' => 'date_popup',
  '#title' => t( 'Date and time from' ),
  '#default_value' =>date('Y-m-d'),
  '#date_format' => 'Y-m-d H:i:s',
  '#date_year_range' => '-5:0',
```

);

Answer (score 1):

This is not a really Drupal related question since you just need to change the default datetime value of a variable. Just create a variable for the default time and follow the instructions from here:

[Get timestamp of today and yesterday in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780333/get-timestamp-of-today-and-yesterday-in-php)

or

[PHP date yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796866/php-date-yesterday)

```
// If you want to have a date of yesterday at 10:00. You need to add seconds here.    
$default_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("yesterday") +  60 * 60 * 60 * 10 );

$form['create_from'] = array(
 '#type' => 'date_popup',
 '#title' => t( 'Date and time from' ),
 '#default_value' => $default_date, // Use the $default_date value from above
 '#date_format' => 'Y-m-d H:i:s',
 '#date_year_range' => '-5:0',
);
```