# Codeigniter : compare timestamp value from database against current date

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

In my database i've timestamp col. i want to fetch check if for particular user whats the date for timestamp col , if its not today (yesterday) show a specific message .

This is my timestamp value for a particular user for today :**1482048000**.

No i want to loop through table like this

```
$this->db->get_where ('tbl_name', array('userid->'$id, time ...));
```

in time i want to check if its today or  yesterday. How do i check this , Please help

Answer (score 1):

Well this is a great example of why storing php timestamps is not a great idea in a mysql database. You should really have converted the timestamp to a MYSQL date and stored it in a datetime or date data type column, and then it would have been a lot easier.

However, you are where you are, so you need to do something like:

```
$this->db->from('tbl_name')
   ->where('user_id', $user_id)
   ->where('time >', $timestamp)
   ->get();
```

$timestamp is the php timestamp for the date you want, ie yesterday at midnight (I presume you want, not just the previous 48 or 24 hour period).

To get the $timestamp you would just do some php date manipulation something like as described here:
[Get timestamp of today and yesterday in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780333/get-timestamp-of-today-and-yesterday-in-php)

Or something like:

```
$timestamp = strtotime('yesterday midnight');
```

EDIT:
I may have misunderstood your question. On second reading you seem to be asking how do you (having read an entries timestamp from your database) know if it is yesterday or today?

This has already been answered [PHP How to find the time elapsed since a date time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915864/php-how-to-find-the-time-elapsed-since-a-date-time) and [Finding the number of days between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040560/finding-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates)